# Finding the mistake in my Dog years to human years program

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I am a beginner in python.

1. If the input is 5 how do i make the output 33 be printed only once?
2. The most important question:Is there an algorithm to replace the need to write 21?

Here is the original question:

> It is commonly said that one human year is equivalent to 7 dog years.Some people believe that it is better to count each of the first two human years as 10.5 dog years, and then count each additional human year as 4 dog years

```py
dog_years=int(input("Enter the age of the dog to get it's equivalent for it's owner:" ))
dog_age_to_human_age_1=10.5*dog_years
dog_age_to_human_age_2=4*(dog_years-2)
dog_1=[]

if dog_years <= 0:
    print("Please Enter an positive integer whole number")
    exit()
elif dog_years > 0 and  dog_years <= 2:
    print(dog_age_to_human_age_1)
    dog_1.append(dog_age_to_human_age_1)


for dog_years in range(3,dog_years+1):
    dog_1.append(dog_age_to_human_age_2)
    print(dog_1[-1]+21)               #is there an algorithm to replace the 21?
```

Comment: Edit your question's title to apply to the question.

Comment: sorry,not clear what are you asking,could you provide a examples and expected output

Comment: you have a print statement inside the for loop. That's why you're pointing multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your code a little bit to have the functionality I understood was required:

```
# Algorithmic solution

dog_years = int(input("Enter the age of the dog to get it's equivalent for it's owner:" ))

young_year = 10.5
old_year = 4

human_age = 0

if dog_years < 0:
    print("Please Enter a positive integer whole number")
else:
    for i in range(dog_years):
        if i < 2:
            human_age += young_year
        else:
            human_age += old_year
    print(f"Your dog is {human_age} human years old.")
```

You could replace the for-loop with NumPy like so:

```
arr = np.ones(dog_years)
arr[:2] *= young_year
arr[2:] *= old_year
human_age = np.sum(arr)
```

This problem might be more elegantly solved arithmetically:

```
# Arithmetic solution
if dog_years < 0:
    print("Please Enter a positive integer whole number")
elif dog_years <= 2:
    human_age = dog_years * young_year
else:
    human_age = 2 * young_year + (dog_years - 2) * old_year
```

Comment: "You might be curious to find out more about NumPy"--curious why for this simple problem and posters beginning level of coding experience?

Comment: I've added a solution with numpy and an arithmetic solution. Since the OP is learning python, I thought a solution in numpy would be interesting to him. But I might only assume that because of my preference for numpy. If you think this is not helpful in my answer, I'm happy to delete it.

Comment: @Benji--actually my only point was that as a beginner he should have a good understanding of the basics before trying more advanced Python modules like numpy.  The questionnaire asks "#is there an algorithm to replace the 21".  I think your arithmetic solution is a cleverer implementation of their for loop solution.  However, I think your arithmetic solution is even better since it's faster (i.e. constant time), simpler, and just uses things a beginning to Python would know.  Overall, I would keep both solutions for presentation to the user.

Comment: @Benji--FYI--as another solution, in terms of performance timing tests show the following simple Python loop runs several times faster than the Numpy code: `sum(young_year if i < 2 else old_year for i in range(dog_years))`

Comment: @DarryIG thank you for sharing this really neat and brief solution! Regarding performance, do you have a specific reference in mind? I've just done a timing test and python is faster for values below ~100, but starting from ~1000 numpy outperforms python by far. So considering this specific use-case of turning dog age into human age I concede that you are right.

Comment: @Benji--just posted test example.  Think dog ages should only in the range of 0-25 (practically speaking).   So performed testing with different lengths of random ages from 2 to 2**17.

Answer (score 0):

Performance of Different Conversion Techniques

Examined the following methods

1. Arithmetic -- O(1) complexity
2. For Loop -- O(n) complexity, where n is the year
3. Numpy -- O(n) complexity, where n is the year
4. Generator -- O(n) complexity, where n is the year

**Results**

*Test 1: Varying length of list of ages, with random ages between 0 to 25*

- Best performance using arithmetic
- For loop and generator similar
- Numpy worst performance

*Test 2: Varied age from 0 to 2**10 (although ages above 25 unrealistic for dogs)*

- Arithmetic best performer at all ages
- For loop better than generator for ages less than 20
- For loop better than generator above 20
- Numpy better than for loop and generator above age 100 but worst otherwise

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint
import perfplot

def test_arithmetic(test_years):
  " Arithmetic method test "
  def calc_arithmetic(dog_years):
    " arithmetic conversion O(1) complexity "
    return young_year*dog_years if dog_years <= 2 else 2*young_year + (dog_years-2)*old_year

  for years in test_years:
    " Perform over the designated years "
    calc_arithmetic(years)

def test_for_loop(test_years):
  " For loop test runs "
  def calc_for_loop(dog_years):
    human_age = 0
    for i in range(dog_years):
      if i < 2:
        human_age += young_year
      else:
        human_age += old_year
    return human_age

  for years in test_years:
    " Perform over the designated years "
    calc_for_loop(years)

def test_np(test_years):
 " Numpy method test runs "
  def calc_np(years):
    " convert using numpy "
    arr = np.ones(years)
    arr[:2] *= young_year
    arr[2:] *= old_year
    return np.sum(arr)

  for years in test_years:
    " Perform over the designated years "
    calc_np(years)

def test_generator(test_years):
  def calc_list(years):
    " convert using generator "
    return sum(young_year if i < 2 else old_year for i in range(years))

  for years in test_years:
    " Perform over the designated years "
    calc_list(years)

young_year = 10.5
old_year = 4
```

**Test 1: Random age from 0 to 25, varying the number of ages**

```
# Time using perfplot (https://pypi.org/project/perfplot/)
perfplot.show(
   setup=lambda n: [randint(0, 25) for _ in range(n)],  # or simply setup=numpy.random.rand
    kernels=[test_arithmetic, test_np, test_for_loop, test_generator],
    labels=['arithmetic', 'numpy', 'for_loop', 'generator'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(17)],
    xlabel="List Length",
    equality_check= None,
    target_time_per_measurement=1.0
    )
```

*Output*

[image: Performance Comparision]

**Test 2: Varying Age from 0 to 1024 in Years**

```
perfplot.show(
   setup=lambda n: [n],  # or simply setup=numpy.random.rand
    kernels=[test_arithmetic, test_np, test_for_loop, test_generator],
    labels=['arithmetic', 'numpy', 'for_loop', 'generator'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(10)],
    xlabel="Years",
    equality_check= None,
    target_time_per_measurement=1.0
    )
```

*Output*
[image]

Comment: @DarryIG that's a great comparison of runtime behavior! Thank you! Test 2 perfectly visualizes what I was considering when writing my other comment. Yet, I would like to point out that Test 1 has a rather obvious result, since each test-function is just a for-loop calling a constant-time function, so runtime increase is linear due to python's for-loop. The beauty of NumPy will outperform vanilla Python if you **replace the for-loop** calling ``calc_np(years)`` **with NumPy functionality**.

Comment: @Benji--For Test 1--with random age between 0-25, the average is 12.5, so you expect to have this many for loops on average.  At this level Numpy is worst, as shown by Test 2.  What's interesting about Numpy is that performance is relatively flat (only slowly increasing).  This points out some fixed overhead which makes it only worthwhile for larger problem sizes (i.e. loops over 100 in this case).  This is often what you see with Numpy--that it's often only better than Pure Python for larger problems. Thus unless you're doing complex computations pure Python is often better.